# Cannot re-enable TypeSctipt import intention

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.3

On PhpStorm 2016.3.2 (Ubuntu) I accidentally disabled some option from intentions dropdown (Alt+Enter) for a particular module name.

Now PhpStorm won't suggest import `Component`, but it works fine with any other Angular module, like `Input` etc.

I cleared cache, reinstalled all project from scratch, cleared .idea file - yet no luck.

I wonder if I can find any exceptions config or a blacklist so that I could restore behavior for name `Component`.

Comment: Intention settings are stored at IDE-wide level settings (affect all projects) so clearing `.idea` and re-creating project will do nothing. If it was actually disabled Intention -- have a look at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Intentions`

Comment: What surprised me, is that on other Angular application the import suggestion seems to be working.

Comment: In such case it should be an Inspection (that supplies Intention/quick fix). Creating project from scratch with deleting `.idea` subfolder should solved it. In any case -- compare what Inspection profiles those 2 projects use (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`) -- go trough all relevant inspections and see if you can find the right one. I cannot give you any better suggestion I'm afraid -- not a TypeScript/Angular user myself.